# C# Creating Custom Chart Class

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

It's been a while since I did something like this, however I am trying to create a custom chart class derived from the DataVisualization.Chart class, 
I have the following

```
public class clsCustomChart:System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
{

    public clsCustomChart(string strChartTitle, double[] dblX, double[] dblY)
    {
        //  Create the chart

        //  Create the chart
        Chart chartReturn = new Chart();
        chartReturn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.DarkGray);
        chartReturn.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        chartReturn.BorderlineColor = Color.Black;
        chartReturn.Width = 300;
        chartReturn.Height = 300;

        //  Create the legend
        Legend l = new Legend("Legend");
        l.Docking = Docking.Bottom;
        l.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        chartReturn.Legends.Add(l);

        //  Create the chart area
        ChartArea a = new ChartArea("ChartArea1");
        a.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
        a.Area3DStyle.WallWidth = 0;
        a.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Black);

        chartReturn.ChartAreas.Add(a);

        //  Create the axis
        a.AxisX.LineColor = Color.Silver;
        a.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
        a.AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
        a.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Black);
        a.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8F);

        a.AxisY.LineColor = Color.Silver;
        a.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
        a.AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
        a.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Black);
        a.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8F);

        //  Chart title
        chartReturn.Titles.Add(new Title(strChartTitle));

        //  Add the data
        //  Create the data series
        Series s = new Series("IN");
        s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        dblX.ToList<double>().ForEach(x => { s.Points.Add(x); });
        s.Color = Color.FromArgb(200, Color.Red);
        s.BorderWidth = 3;

        Series s2 = new Series("OUT");
        s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        dblY.ToList<double>().ForEach(x => { s2.Points.Add(x); });
        s2.Color = Color.FromArgb(200, Color.Green);
        s2.BorderWidth = 3;

        chartReturn.Series.Add(s);
        chartReturn.Series.Add(s2);

        chartReturn.SaveImage("c:/test/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".jpeg", ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);

    }

}
```

The code that is in the custom chart is all tested and working fine, when creating as a chart object, and the custom class saves the chart as image fine.

However, when I try this in a form

```
Chart C = (Chart)new clsCustomChart("TEST",x,y);

this.Controls.Add(C);
```

I don't get the chart...... can anyone advise.....

TIA

Comment: can you add the DataVisualization Chart control to the window form and see how the IDE is adding the code? From there, you can replace the Chart type with your own derived type.

Comment: Are you trying to "return" a value from a constructor? The chart you are defining is nested within your custom control, and not the custom control itself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand?  I've used my code from the class in the form, on form_load, and it draws the chart fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//  Create the chart
Chart chartReturn = new Chart();
```

This creates a chart which you then style and throw away.

Delete it and replace `chartReturn` with `this`!

Also you may want to provide a **parameterless** constructor in case you ever want to place it on a form via the designer..

Comment: I tried, this, first of all, which is what I thought it would be, but I got a readonly, as I was tring to create this, many thanks, I knew my memory wasn't that bad :)